# Is it possible to have a QWidget as a child to a QObject?

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qwidget

My main application object is a `QObject`, that juggles a `QSystemTrayIcon`, a `QDialog`, a `QWindow` and a few other components. The app mostly sits in the tray, with some options dialogs etc etc.

Now, I'd like to use `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName()` to connect signals from these objects to slots in the main object. It's 10-15 of them, so writing them by hand doesn't seem efficient, right, professional, modern, etc etc.

However, I can't use my `QObject` as parent to the `QWidget` based objects, nor can I change the object to inherit `QWidget`, as they will not show up, since the main object isn't visible.

Ideas?

Comment: Related question (not a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/q/28992276/1329652

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting signals to slots manually is perfectly fine. Qt itself is doing that, most Qt applications are doing that.

I'm afraid you can't use `connectSlotsByName` for the parent-child issues with `QWidget`, but if you really want it, you have all the metadata available in `QMetaObject`, so you can write a function that works like `connectSlotsByName` on any pair/set of `QObject`s.

Comment: I connect some slots too, it's just a bother to do it with 10-20 of them. :) .. Writing my own function sounds like a good plan though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could promote the `QObject` to a hidden `QWidget`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28995049/1329652). In a nutshell:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QWidget parent;
   QLabel l1{"Close me to quit!"}, l2{"Hello!"};
   for (auto label : {&l1, &l2}) {
      label->setMinimumSize(200, 100);
      label->setParent(&parent);
      label->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
      label->setText(QString("%1 Parent: %2.").
                     arg(label->text()).arg((quintptr)label->parent(), 0, 16));
      label->show();
   }
   l2.setAttribute(Qt::WA_QuitOnClose, false);
   return app.exec();
}
```