# What are consequences of forcing QObject as a parent of QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

The following code compiles perfectly:

```
QObject* o = new QObject(0);
QWidget* w = new QWidget(0);
qobject_cast<QObject*>(w)->setParent(o);
```

I cannot legally set `QObject` as a parent of `QWidget`. But using `qobject_cast` it is possible. Are there negative consequences?

Comment: Just curious: what is the reason for such hierarchy?

Comment: What?!? QWidget inherits publicly from QObject

Comment: `QWidget::setParent(QWidget*)` hides `QObject::setParent(QObject*)`.

Comment: `static_cast` would be more appropriate. Or `w->QObject::setParent(o);`.

Comment: For those voting to close this as "unclear" - please, don't. It's a perfectly clear question! A *related* one is http://stackoverflow.com/q/1585998/1329652 - but they are *not* duplicates, I don't think.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> What are consequences of forcing QObject as a parent of QWidget?

Irrevocable undefined behavior.

Qt is not designed to support a non-widget parent to a `QWidget`. I consider it an API bug in Qt, since a `QWidget` isn't fully a `QObject` in the Liskov Substitution Principle sense because of that limitation.

Qt 4.x will crash when attempting to activate the widget. So it'll work until you focus your application and then will crash.

Qt 5.x asserts in `QObject::setParent()`.

The assertion can be bypassed, though:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/widget-parent-28992276
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

class ParentHacker : private QWidget {
public:
   static void setParent(QWidget * child_, QObject * parent) {
      // The following line invokes undefined behavior
      auto child = static_cast<ParentHacker*>(child_);
      Q_ASSERT(child->d_ptr->isWidget);
      child->d_ptr->isWidget = 0;
      child->QObject::setParent(parent);
      child->d_ptr->isWidget = 1;
   }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QLabel w{"Hello!"};
   w.setMinimumSize(200, 100);
   w.show();
   ParentHacker::setParent(&w, &app);
   return app.exec();
}
```

It will crash somewhere else then.

You'd be fighting an uphill battle trying to patch Qt to get it to work. It's not a worthwhile fight, I think - not unless a decision is made to make a `QWidget` truly-a `QObject` and change its constructor signature. That can be done at the earliest in the next major version of Qt since it's a binary-incompatible change AFAIK.

Moreover, what you're trying to do is mostly unnecessary. You can certainly have a hidden `QWidget` parent to multiple stand-alone top-level widgets.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QWidget parent;
   QLabel l1{"Close me to quit!"}, l2{"Hello!"};
   for (auto label : {&l1, &l2}) {
      label->setMinimumSize(200, 100);
      label->setParent(&parent);
      label->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
      label->setText(QString("%1 Parent: %2.").
                     arg(label->text()).arg((quintptr)label->parent(), 0, 16));
      label->show();
   }
   l2.setAttribute(Qt::WA_QuitOnClose, false);
   return app.exec();
}
```

The overhead of having the widget hidden is minimal, you're not wasting any resources by using a `QWidget` instead of a `QObject` for the parent.