# How to make event filter that deletes itself when corresponding QObject has been deleted?

Tags: qt

I have an event filter object that is installed like this:

```
someQObject.installEventFilter( new MyEventFilterObject() );
```

I need to ensure that the allocated memory for `MyEventFilterObject` is freed when `someQObject` is deleted. Does QObject emit any event when it's deleted? Or how can I know that it's been deleted and delete the event filter?

Comment: Can't you just have someQObject as parent to MyEventFilterObject?

Comment: And that would result in automatic deletion? Because I sure can, but I thought that hierarchy only works for widgets.

Comment: The destructor of a parent QObject destroys all child objects.

Comment: You should go for the set parent approach as it is a simpler solution, but since you asked, there is a [`QObject::destroyed`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed) signal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I thought that hierarchy only works for widgets.

The object ownership is implemented by `QObject`. The `QWidget` simply inherits from `QObject`. In fact, `QWidget` is a bit of a special case: it can have `QObject` children, but [can't have a parent that's not a `QWidget`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28992276/1329652).

All you need to do is parent the filter to the object it's installed on:

```
MyEventFilterObject::MyEventFilterObject(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    //...
}

someQObject.installEventFilter(new MyEventFilterObject(someQObject));
```

> Does QObject emit any event when it's deleted?

It's hard to talk of an object emitting an event. Events are *targeted* at a particular receiver. The sender of the event must be aware of the recipient a-priori. An event can be sent at any time, to any object, by any code - even code running in a non-Qt thread and not using any other aspect of Qt functionality. In case of a generic `QObject`, it could send an event to its parent and/or its children, and that's about it. Otherwise, it has no knowledge of any other objects.

`QObject` does emit a *signal* from its destuctor, though: `QObject::destroyed(QObject*)`. You could have the event filter destroy itself when that signal is emitted:

```
QObject * chainDestroy(QObject * src, QObject * dst) {
  QObject::connect(src, &QObject::destroyed, dst, &QObject::deleteLater);
  return dst;
}
auto filter = chainDestroy(&someQObject, new MyEventFilterObject);
someQObject.installEventFilter(filter);
```

If you can, simply set the parent on the filter. If the filter needs to have a different parent, then connect the signal as above.

> how can I know that it's been deleted and delete the event filter?

You could simply make the event filter a permanent object - you only need one per thread. One event filter can be installed on as many objects as you wish, as long as they all live in the same thread. You can certainly do that unless the event filter is stateful, and its state is specific to the object it's filtering on.